# How optimise nested looping in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am new to JavaScript ES6. I want to convert nested looping to single looping in my code. I have some examples below can anyone help me out how to make it single loop. Is it possible for my below code. As I know that in JavaScript Nested loop is not good for performance.

**No 1:**

```
  getCountryNames = (cList, countryCodeList) => {
    const list = [];
    countryCodeList.forEach(code => {
      cList.forEach(cjson => {
        if (cjson.code === code) {
          list.push(cjson.label);
        }
      });
    });
    return list;
  }
```

**No 2:**

```
  getITestList = () => {
    const msgArr = this.state.bufferMsgList;
    const arr = [];
    msgArr.forEach(msg => {
      let flag = true;
      if (arr.length > 0) {
        arr.forEach(data => {
          if (data.id === msg.group_entity_id) {
            flag = false;
          }
        });
      }
      if (flag) {
        const json = {
          id: msg.group_entity_id,
          code: msg.group_entity_code,
        };
        arr.push(json);
      }
    });
    return arr;
  }
```

**No 3:**

```
  getMsgWithTest = (list) => {
    const responseArr = [];
    if (list.length > 0) {
      list.forEach(payload => {
        const messageList = payload.messages;
        if (messageList) {
          messageList.forEach(msg => {
            const mjson = Object.assign({}, msg);
            mjson.group_entity_code = payload.group_entity_code;
            mjson.group_entity_id = payload.group_entity_id;
            responseArr.push(mjson);
          });
        }
      });
    }
    return responseArr;
  }
```

**No 4:**

```
this.state.defaultMessageList.forEach(payload => {
  if (payload.messages) {
    payload.messages.forEach(msg => {
      filteredRegionBasedOnMsg.push(msg.regions);
      filteredCountryBasedOnMsg.push(msg.country_codes);
    });
  }
});
```

No 5:

```
  this.state.defaultMessageList.forEach(payload => {
    if (payload.messages) {
      payload.messages.forEach(msg => {
        if (msg.status === 'ACTIVE') {
          filteredCountryBasedOnMsg.push(msg.country_codes);
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

Comment: It's a bit of a misconception that "JavaScript Nested loop is not good for performance" as a blanket statement, there can be more/less efficient implementations, but generally if you need to access/compare from two or more sets of data a nested loop is a valid method. The problem is really when you have unnecessary nested loops or each loop is doing more work than it needs to.

Comment: Many of these can be sped up with `Set`s to keep track of seen values.

Comment: Check out the Big O Notation concepts, it may share some light on how loops could affect performance https://developerinsider.co/big-o-notation-explained-with-examples/